# Java Convert two char Operator String to working Operator?

Tags: java, arrays, char

```java
Have char[] operator = // "+" or "<" or "<=" etc
  if(op.length == 1) {
    switch (op[0]) {
      case '+':
        if (a instanceof Double || b instanceof Double) {
          result = a.doubleValue() + b.doubleValue();
        } else if (a instanceof Long && b instanceof Long) {
          result = a.longValue() + b.longValue();
        }
        break;
      case '-':
        if (a instanceof Double || b instanceof Double) {
          result = a.doubleValue() - b.doubleValue();
        } else if (a instanceof Long && b instanceof Long) {
          result = a.longValue() - b.longValue();
        }
        break;
      case '*':
        if (a instanceof Double || b instanceof Double) {
          result = a.doubleValue() * b.doubleValue();
        } else if (a instanceof Long && b instanceof Long) {
          result = a.longValue() * b.longValue();
        }
        break;
      case '^':
        if (a instanceof Double || b instanceof Double) {
          result = Double.valueOf(Math.pow(a.doubleValue(), b.doubleValue()));
        } else if (a instanceof Long && b instanceof Long) {
          result = (long) Math.pow(a.longValue(), b.longValue());
        }
        break;
      case '/':
        if (b.doubleValue() == 0) {
          throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Cannot divide by zero");
        }
        if (a instanceof Double || b instanceof Double) {
          result = a.doubleValue() / b.doubleValue();
        } else if (a instanceof Long && b instanceof Long) {
          result = a.longValue() / b.longValue();
        }
        break;
      case '>':
        resultDecorator.setTypeOfexpresion(EvaluatorConstants.Boolean);
      if (a instanceof Double || b instanceof Double) {
        result = a.doubleValue() > b.doubleValue()?1:0;
      } else if (a instanceof Long && b instanceof Long) {
        result = a.longValue() > b.longValue()?1:0;
      }
      break;
    case '<':
      resultDecorator.setTypeOfexpresion(EvaluatorConstants.Boolean);
      if (a instanceof Double || b instanceof Double) {
        result = a.doubleValue() < b.doubleValue()?1:0;
      } else if (a instanceof Long && b instanceof Long) {
        result = a.longValue() < b.longValue()?1:0;
      }
      break;
    }
  } else if (op.length == 2) {
    resultDecorator.setTypeOfexpresion(EvaluatorConstants.Boolean);
    switch (op.toString()) {
      case ">=":
        if (a instanceof Double || b instanceof Double) {
          result = a.doubleValue() >= b.doubleValue()?1:0;
        } else if (a instanceof Long && b instanceof Long) {
          result = a.longValue() >= b.longValue()?1:0;
        }
        break;
      case "<=":
        if (a instanceof Double || b instanceof Double) {
          result = a.doubleValue() <= b.doubleValue()?1:0;
        } else if (a instanceof Long && b instanceof Long) {
          result = a.longValue() <= b.longValue()?1:0;
        }
        break;
          case "==":
            if (a instanceof Double || b instanceof Double) {
              result = a.doubleValue() == b.doubleValue()?1:0;
            } else if (a instanceof Long && b instanceof Long) {
              result = a.longValue() == b.longValue()?1:0;
            }
            break;
          }
        }
```

Wanted to avoid many comparison operations.

I don't see a solution to covert string to literal I mean convert to working operator(single char operator or two char operator).

Can it be achieved without using any lib?

Comment: What is the type of `a` and `b`? What happen if the `a` is an instance of `Double` and `b` is an instance of `Long`?

Comment: How these two chars came into the array? do you have some kind of scanner/lexical analyzer? why don't you use an enum type instead?

Comment: @MauricePerry Yes iterative of reading each char from string expression

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert each one of these into [BiFunctions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/BiFunction.html).

```
    if (a instanceof Double || b instanceof Double) {
      result = a.doubleValue() + b.doubleValue();
    } else if (a instanceof Long && b instanceof Long) {
      result = a.longValue() + b.longValue();
    }
```

And put them into a map using the operator as key. Your big if-else-switch statement becomes:

```
result = operatorMap.get(op.toString()).apply(a, b);
```

Answer (score 2):

As always, avoid repetition by moving common code into methods. The struggle seems to be with the passing of the actual operations as arguments. One solution could be

```java
switch(operator.length == 1? operator[0]: operator[0] << 16 | operator[1])
{
  case '+': result = perform(a, b, Double::sum, Long::sum); break;
  case '-': result = perform(a, b, (d1, d2) -> d1 - d2, (l1, l2) -> l1 - l2); break;
  case '*': result = perform(a, b, (d1, d2) -> d1 * d2, (l1, l2) -> l1 * l2); break;
  case '/': result = perform(a, b, (d1, d2) -> d1 / check(d2),(l1, l2) -> l1 / l2);break;
  case '%': result = perform(a, b, (d1, d2) -> d1 % check(d2),(l1, l2) -> l1 % l2);break;
  case '^': result = perform(a, b, Math::pow, (l1, l2) -> (long)Math.pow(l1, l2)); break;
  case '>':
    resultDecorator.setTypeOfexpresion(EvaluatorConstants.Boolean);
    result = performCmp(a, b, (d1, d2) -> d1 > d2, (l1, l2) -> l1 > l2);
    break;
  case '<':
    resultDecorator.setTypeOfexpresion(EvaluatorConstants.Boolean);
    result = performCmp(a, b, (d1, d2) -> d1 < d2, (l1, l2) -> l1 < l2);
    break;
  case '<' << 16 | '=':
    resultDecorator.setTypeOfexpresion(EvaluatorConstants.Boolean);
    result = performCmp(a, b, (d1, d2) -> d1 <= d2, (l1, l2) -> l1 <= l2);
    break;
  case '>' << 16 | '=':
    resultDecorator.setTypeOfexpresion(EvaluatorConstants.Boolean);
    result = performCmp(a, b, (d1, d2) -> d1 >= d2, (l1, l2) -> l1 >= l2);
    break;
  case '=' << 16 | '=':
    resultDecorator.setTypeOfexpresion(EvaluatorConstants.Boolean);
    result = performCmp(a, b, (d1, d2) -> d1 == d2, (l1, l2) -> l1 == l2);
    break;
  default: throw new ArithmeticException("unknown operator " + new String(operator));
}
```

```java
static Number perform(
    Number a, Number b, DoubleBinaryOperator dOp, LongBinaryOperator lOp)
{
  return a instanceof Double || b instanceof Double?
      dOp.applyAsDouble(a.doubleValue(), b.doubleValue()):
      lOp.applyAsLong(a.longValue(), b.longValue());
}

@FunctionalInterface interface BinaryDoublePredicate
{
  boolean test(double d1, double d2);
}

@FunctionalInterface interface BinaryLongPredicate
{
  boolean test(long d1, long d2);
}

static Number performCmp(
    Number a, Number b, BinaryDoublePredicate dOp, BinaryLongPredicate lOp)
{
  return (a instanceof Double || b instanceof Double?
      dOp.test(a.doubleValue(), b.doubleValue()):
      lOp.test(a.longValue(), b.longValue()))? 1: 0;
}

static double check(double d2)
{
  if(d2 == 0) throw new ArithmeticException("/ by zero");
  return d2;
}
```

Note that when using the better suited `ArithmeticException` instead of `UnsupportedOperationException` for division by zero, you get it for free when performing `/` or `%` on `long`. Only for the `double` operation, an explicit check is needed when you want to get an exception rather than `NaN`.

The code above also handles the one-char and two-char values with a single `switch` statement as an `int` can easily contain two chars. The only drawback is that it would handle `"\0+"` like `"+"` but such input should be ruled out by the preceding processing operation already.

Comment: Thank you Holger :-) i could avoid many if's using your code.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a table of binary operators. For instance, the following class could be used to model one of these binary operators:

```
public class Operator2<T1 extends Number, T2 extends Number> {
    private final Class<T1> t1;
    private final Class<T2> t2;
    private final BiFunction<T1,T2,?> op;

    public Operator2(
            Class<T1> t1, Class<T2> t2, BiFunction<T1,T2,?> op) {
        this.t1 = t1;
        this.t2 = t2;
        this.op = op;
    }

    public boolean canApplyTo(Number a, Number b) {
        return canConvert(a.getClass(), t1) && canConvert(b.getClass(), t2);
    }

    public Object apply(Number a, Number b) {
        return op.apply((T1)convert(a, t1), (T2)convert(b, t2));
    }

    private static boolean canConvert(
            Class<? extends Number> s, Class<? extends Number> t) {
        if (s == t) {
            return true;
        }
        if (t == Double.class) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private static Number convert(Number v, Class<? extends Number> t) {
        if (v.getClass() == t) {
            return v;
        }
        if (t == Double.class) {
            return v.doubleValue();
        }
        return 0L;
    }
}
```

The next class is a table of binary operators:

```
public class Operator2Table {
    private final Map<String,List<Operator2<?,?>>> map = new HashMap<>();

    public Operator2Table() {
        register("+", Long.class, Long.class, (a,b) -> a+b);
        register("+", Double.class, Double.class, (a,b) -> a+b);
        // ...
    }

    public Object apply(String s, Number a, Number b) {
        List<Operator2<?,?>> list = map.get(s);
        if (list == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown operator " + s);
        }
        for (Operator2<?,?> op: list) {
            if (op.canApplyTo(a, b)) {
                return op.apply(a, b);
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot apply operator " + s
                + " to given argument");
    }

    private <T1 extends Number,T2 extends Number>
         void register(String s, Class<T1> t1, Class<T2> t2, BiFunction<T1,T2,?> op) {
        List<Operator2<?,?>> list = map.get(s);
        if (list == null) {
            list = new ArrayList<>();
            map.put(s, list);
        }
        list.add(new Operator2<>(t1, t2, op));
    }
}
```

Note that it is important that you register the `Long` version of a given operator before the `Double` version because the `Double` version can also be applied to two `Long`s whereas the `Long` version cannot be applied to two `Double`s.

These tables are very flexible, and you could easily extend the code to support `Int`s, `Short`s and `Float`s.